# How to define your own fill method parameter in pandas (python)?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Some DataFrame and Series methods have the method parameter. For example:

```
DataFrame.fillna(value=None, method=None, axis=None, inplace=False, limit=None, downcast=None, **kwargs)
```

and the method parameter can take the following values: {None, ‘backfill’/’bfill’, ‘pad’/’ffill’, ‘nearest’}

However I'd like to **def** some sort of a fill-in-function which would in turn define how to fill in the gaps by using the values already present in the Series, so that it could be used in the following way:

```
df = DataFrame.fillna(method='new_method')
```

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you want? From what I understand, it sounds like you would need to monkey-patch the `fillna` method, or modify the source code, since the `method` parameter doesn't accept an arbitrary function.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yeah I think the right way to go would be to modify the source code. Well e.g. I want a function that would fill in the gaps with the average of the nearest values in the Series. I mean something like this: 1 NaN 3 --> 1 2 3.

Comment: Is there some reason why you must be able to use it with the `fillna` method? It would likely be better to write your own function and leave the source-code alone.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Not really. But I think it will be possible to use it with all the other methods...like reindex etc. Why do you think so? From what I know, it's common practice to modify the source code when you want to define some custom action.

Comment: Changing the code of a complex library without being aware of all the consequences is generally not a good idea. Of course you can try, but probably as a last resort or when you want to start contributing to pandas for real.

Comment: You would have to modify the source-code for *every* method you want to be able to pass a new argument to the `method` parameter, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @honza_p Actually I agree, I meant to say, maby, redefine some class methods or smth like that. I've never done this before myself. But it surely requires a good understanding of the source code.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga probably you're right.

Comment: Based on the comments, what you are really asking for is [`interpolate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.interpolate.html) method and specifically it's forward  linear interpolation. For eg - `pd.Series([1,np.NaN,3]).interpolate()` gives you [1,2,3]

Answer (score 0):

In your **very specific** case (average of the nearest values), you can do this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

col1 = np.array([0, 1, np.nan, 4])
col2 = np.array([0, np.nan, 2, 5])

df = pd.DataFrame({"col1" : col1, "col2" : col2})

# Trick: average forward and backward fill
df = 0.5 * (df.fillna(method="bfill") + df.fillna(method="ffill"))
```

By averaging the backward and forward fill, you will get the average while keeping all other values (but for rounding error) unchanged. But it will not work for the first and last row, of course. (But then you can use ffill and bfill once more if that is acceptable)

Comment: well in truth, it was more of a curiosity question than anything else. I'd just like to know if it's possible to redifine, say, *something* to enable me to set a custom method parameter. I know, it's almost always possible to find a workaround that would do the trick.